# Unable to deploy app on app engine using cloud build from github

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to implement CI/CD functionality using cloud build I have repository available on github. I have integrated my github repository with cloud source repository.Now after creating build triggers when I am running it is showing error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a cloudbuild.yaml in the current directory, and the runtime field in /workspace/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: nodejs]. To use your cloudbuild.yaml to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [nodejs] runtime, please remove the cloudbuild.yaml from this directory.

Here is  my **cloudbuild.yaml** file:

```
steps:

#Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
args: ['clone', 'https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders']

#Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

**app.yaml**

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
```

Someone please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1):

Try moving all project files including the `app.yaml` into a subdirectory except `couldbuild.yaml` and specify the subdirectory containing them in the `couldbuild.yaml` :

```
#Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '[SUBDIRECTORY/app.yaml]']
```

Comment: I have created subdirectory myapp and moved app.yaml into that but it is saying ``ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/workspace/[myapp/app.yaml]] does not exist. Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud``

Comment: I did a quick test on my end and it worked. From the error, it looks like it's not finding that directory.  Try removing the brackets (`[]`) around the `app.yaml` location. Also, is 'workspace' another subdirectory you created that contains 'myapp'? If it's the parent directory, I don't think you need to include it. Anyhow, try changing it to this: `- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      args: ['app', 'deploy', 'myapp/app.yaml']`

Comment: NO I don't have any workspace subdirectory I have parent directory under which i have ``cloudbuild.yaml``  file exist and one subdirectory named ``myapp`` under parent directory which has ``app.yaml`` file.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error after changing the code to what I suggested you in my last comment? Also, is it a Docker build in Cloud Build?

Comment: I am not deploying using docker i am deploying on app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud build builds a Docker file that already specifies the runtime, so you won't have to re-specify it again in app.yaml. It's perfectly fine to change the runtime in app.yaml to custom.

Comment: When I am adding ``runtime: custom`` i am getting following ``ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You must provide your own Dockerfile when using a custom runtime. Otherwise provide a "runtime" field with one of the supported runtimes.``